Develop a toaster as open source
I would like to build a toaster just like building software on GitHub. The project should have documentation and allow people interested in the development of the project to contribute. Collaboration should be possible especially in the development of 3 elements. Does anyone have any ideas on how to set something like this up?

Might I ask why? A toaster is a good example of something mass produced that couldn't possibly be built cheaper or better by oneself. Add to this the fact that a home built toaster is very possibly a fire risk argues against the idea.

Just do it. Put the design documents on github and let people decide if its worth it or not. Who cares if its cheaper or not. Safety? Sure, needs to be adressed.

Be careful, we don't want toasters like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vLm6oTCFcxQ

I'll go along with @joojaa, while there are plenty of toasters out there of many designs, it would be interesting to have a new open/collaborative design.  If you look at github projects, they mostly start with one person and once it gets going, others add/update/continue.  "If you build a better [toaster], ..." (full quote here Maybe not but there are plenty of neat open projects out there. Look up blowtorches.  1000s of people improved on designs back and forth with good results.

a toaster that 3D prints toast ... or laser engraved toast

I think your question is too vague. You should start by looking at other open source mechanical projects to see how they do it.

This project doesn't necessarily need to be cheap and could compete with high end toasters.

@erics I want to build a toaster that is as resource-efficient as possible. It should be durable, modular, easy to repair, and affordable. It will be built by the community, for the community.

@Drew do you have some example. I found nothing and decided to to as here after the research

Ok looks like open source is always github. Sample from arduino project https://www.arduino.cc/en/contribute

@Cangoo Here's one: https://github.com/Sillybutts/SLAB

Being resource efficient might be a problem, not much more resource efficient stuff than deep drawing or injection moulding. Problem being not for singular items. Just make a toaster.

Looks like open source is always github.
Like @joojaa said "...Put the design documents on github..."
Sample from arduino project arduino.cc/en/contribute –
Here is another one sample provided by by @Drew github.com/Sillybutts/SLAB
